# Did something change with the mod tools for high-rep users?

Tags: support, privileges

I've been getting notifications of proposed edits for several months now, but today I found a little yellow box where the orange "suggested edits" button usually is. Upon clicking it directed me to three questions, all of which appeared to have close votes (for one reason or another).

Is this new functionality of some sort, or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a new functionality that changes what flags are visible. Instead of spam/offensive flags, you now see various generic moderator flags (anonymized, of course), and can perform your own corresponding action (vote to close, or flag).

Today, their presence has been added to the top navigation bar.

Read up on more details [on this thread from Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93623/feedback-on-tools-flagged-changes).